# Select min price from relational database

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm trying to select a list of products with the lowest possible price for each product listed. To put in context, I have these tables:

```
**tb_product**
id | product | active | image | description
1  | shoes A |    1   | ...   | ...
2  | shirt C |    1   | ...   | ...
4  | pants E |    1   | ...   | ...
---

**tb_store**
id | name    | phone
11 | Store X | ...
22 | Store F | ...
33 | Store K | ...
---

**tb_product_store** 
id_product | id_store | price
1          | 11       | 9.90
1          | 22       | 12.90
2          | 11       | 15.90
2          | 33       | 12.90
4          | 33       | 22.90
---
```

For example, I want to select all the products that are listed on the table `tb_product_store` with the lowest price, so the result would be something like this:

```
id_product | product | price
1          | shoes A | 9.90
2          | shirt C | 12.90
4          | pants E | 22.90
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.product,
    MIN(b.price) as 'price'

FROM tb_product a 
    JOIN tb_product_store b ON b.id_product = a.id

WHERE a.active = 1
ORDER BY a.product
```

However this query returns only one product with the lowest price, instead of the list with all the products and it's lowest prices.

How can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.product,
   b.price as 'price'
FROM tb_product a 
join (select id_product, min(price)
       from tb_product_store group by id_product) b
     on b.id_product = a.id
whera a.active = 1
order by a.product
```

Comment: You should add an explanation. Code only answers aren't great for future readers with the same problem.

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone is interested.

Comment: Most readers don't have accounts, and certainly don't leave feedback on answers. Also, the community as a whole are on the same page, code only answers are generally discouraged. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-an-explanation-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-ans, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality

Comment: No it's a valid answer, just offering some feedback.

Comment: It guided me to solve the issue, but in your code I don't need to do `b.price as 'price'` and instead of `min(price)` I had to do `min(price) as 'price'`. Like @Goose said, it would be nice to have some explanation, because I discovered that if I want to load more data from table `B` I need to declare on the `SELECT` and on the `SELECT` inside the `JOIN` as well.

Comment: If you need this for your job, I'd advise you to learn SQL, eg. read this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/1-4493-1640-9] SQL and Relational Theory.  What I did is define a view on your table tb_product_store, showing only the minimum price of each product available in a store.  I used that view inline, but such view could be defined as a separate object, if you'd need it in many queries.  Forgot to define an alias for the min(price).  If you'd prefer more accurate help, define your problem with http://www.sqlfiddle.com/.  Makes helping you a lot easier.